# Диалог с пользователем PyQT5 (text)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Подскажите, имеется ли возможность в *PyQt5* сделать такой вот серый текст

> **Например: abcdefg**

Когда нажимаешь на виджет, чтобы ввести текст, то эта серая надпись исчезает
и снова появляется, если пользователь ничего не ввёл и убрал курсор.

Pyqt5 умеет ли так делать и как это правильнее называть?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запиши этот тект в атрибут placeholderText

```
textEditor.setPlaceholderText("серый текст.")
```

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#placeholderText-prop

Answer (score 2):

> placeholderText : QString
>
> Это свойство содержит текст-заполнитель редактирования строки.

Больше https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#placeholderText-prop